# Generate Typolink in Backend Environment with Cronjob

Tags: php, cron, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

With TYPO3 9.5 we were able to generate Typolinks from within our Scheduler Class this way:

```
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
$contentRenderer = $objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer::class);
$command = $this->linkCommand($uid, 0);
$uri = $contentRenderer->typoLink_URL($command);
return $uri;
```

With TYPO3 v10 that same code is not working anymore when called via Cronjob.

When running the task manually from within the backend, this code works perfectly fine and generates the URLs based in the page uid. But when running via Cronjob, the following output is generated:

`The parsedUri "http:///www/sites/webXXXX/html/typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3" appears to be malformed`

I tried to generate the links multiple ways, but they all end up with the same error message. I'm not sure what the Cronjob tries here, as the above parsedUri looks completely wrong.

Anybody experiencing similar problems with Cronjobs and TYPO3 v10? Is this server related, or something I could fix via PHP? I really don't know the cause of this.

Comment: Just checked your code in TYPO3 `10.4.12` and it works as expected - generates valid URL to the page record, as you didn't show us declaration of your `linkCommand()` method I copied one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53943153/1066240)

Comment: Also, test [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60725398/1066240) - the first sample works as wanted as well in Scheduler's task in `10.x`

Comment: @biesior The second answer works perfectly fine when using simple UIDs for generating links, thanks. But some links also look like this `t3://page?uid=500#5996` and that function seems to only work with plain uids.

Comment: Indeed `t3://` links can be converted to normal ones using typolink. That means that you need to debug, why your's doesn't work. Show me pls your whole `linkCommand()` method declaration. And also tell, which version of TYPO3 exactly are you using.

Comment: The TYPO3 version is 10.4.13 and the linkCommand() function is essentially the same you can see in your first linked example, except for the language parameter. But I also tried it with the `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\Routing\UriBuilder`. Same issue, won't work with a Cronjob. The problem is that some links need to have an anchor, otherwise I'd just extract the uid from the `t3://` link and leave it like that.

Comment: UriBuilder require a controllers context, it will be difficult to get in in the Scheduler's task. Publish your whole class of the task so one can check.

Answer (score 2):

This work for me in TYPO3 11 used in a middleware.

```
   public function getLink($t3Urn)
    {
//        $t3Urn = 't3://page?uid=500#5996';
        return GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
            \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer::class
        )->typoLink_URL(['parameter'=>$t3Urn]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        //config

        //uid from the page
        $typolinkConfig['parameter'] = $pid;
        //if you want an absolute url. Can work only when the site configuration in the module Sites has a full domain as entry point
        $typolinkConfig['forceAbsoluteUrl'] = true;
        //generate url over cObject. The
        //optional add specific language uid parameter, without default is used
        //$typolinkConfig['language'] = $uidFromNeededLanguage
        $url = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ContentObjectRenderer::class)->typoLink_URL($typolinkConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a shot (untested):

```
$t3Urn = 't3://page?uid=500#5996';

// LinkService to get typolink configuration from t3://...
$typolinkConfig = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\LinkHandling\LinkService::class
)->$linkService->resolve($t3Urn);

// Absolute (if needed). Make sure that Site config contains a full base for the 
// requested page rootline AND that this base is also active in your cron environment.
// If you use application context to resolve bases, add it to the scheduler env:
// TYPO3_CONTEXT=Production/MySubcontext …/vendor/bin/typo3 scheduler:run
$typolinkConfig['forceAbsoluteUrl'] = true;

return GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
  \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer::class
)->typoLink_URL($typolinkConfig);
```

Comment: Didn't work, received an empty string. But I was able to solve it with a workaround now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Andreas could you please tell me about this workaround, since I'm having the exact same issue?

Comment: @biedert I have no access to this project anymore and it's been a while. But I remember just extracting (get everything between `=` and `#`) the page id from the `t3...`link and working my way from there.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks anyways, I solved it by using \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::getPreviewUrl() instead

Comment: Yeah, I think there is no way around getting a real Site with a real SiteLanguage to generate the final URL.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because of the initialization of `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']` within the `AbstractTypolinkBuilder` (at least in CMS11).

If the global does not exist, `ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals()` is being called, which uses `TYPO3_REQUEST_URL`. This is not available/correct within CLI context.

I've fixed this by creating the global before creating a typolink:

```
    /**
     * Create the TYPO3_REQUEST global to prevent creation from ServerRequestFactory which creates it
     * based on TYPO3_REQUEST_URL, which is not available/correct through CLI
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Site\Entity\Site $site
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Site\Entity\SiteLanguage $siteLanguage
     * @return void
     */
    protected function createTypo3Request(Site $site, SiteLanguage $siteLanguage): void
    {
        $request = new ServerRequest(new Uri((string)$siteLanguage->getBase()));
        $request = $request->withAttribute('site', $site);
        $request = $request->withAttribute('language', $siteLanguage);
        $request = $request->withQueryParams(['id' => $site->getRootPageId()]);

        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST'] = $request;
    }
```

Although I think for this to work, your site base has to be an absolute url instead of a relative path.